# javascript function param value reset

Tags: javascript, function, parameters

I am using JavaScript function in single page and I am calling the same function twice without refreshing page and I am also passing params value in function but when I am calling it second time then I am also finding previous time value of params I use at first time call.
For example: I am calling this function and sending '.assign_agents_popup_index' at second time and at first time I am passing '.add_agents_popup_index'.

```
 showUnAssignAgentList('',response, '.assign_agents_popup_index');
```

my question is when i am going into this function and fetching third param second time then i am getting value of previous time as well.

```
 showUnAssignAgentList(cookieLogin, _data, _parent)
```

Example

first time i call this function like :

```
    showUnAssignAgentList('',response, '.add_agents_popup_index');
```

and when fetching param in function then _parent value i am getting '.add_agents_popup_index'
but when i call it second time

```
    showUnAssignAgentList('',response, '.assign_agents_popup_index');
```

then I am getting value of _parent like '.add_agents_popup_index .assign_agents_popup_index' can you tel me how can i reset function value everytime i am calling it

```
function showUnAssignAgentList(cookieLogin, data, _parent) {
var user_data = {},
    sorted_users = [],
    list_names = [];

/* First we're going through the list of users to get the last names */
$.each(data.field_data.users, function(k, v) {
    if(v.last_name && list_names.indexOf(v.last_name.toLowerCase()) < 0) {
        list_names.push(v.last_name.toLowerCase());
    }
});

/* Then we sort the array */
list_names.sort();

/* We build the function which will be use the second time we'll loop over users */
var build_sort_users = function(k, user) {
    if(user.last_name) {
        if(sorted_users[list_names.indexOf(user.last_name.toLowerCase())]) {
            sorted_users[list_names.indexOf(user.last_name.toLowerCase())].push({
                first_name: user.first_name,
                last_name: user.last_name,
                id: user.id
            });
        }
        else {
            sorted_users[list_names.indexOf(user.last_name.toLowerCase())] = [{
                first_name: user.first_name,
                last_name: user.last_name,
                id: user.id
            }];
        }
    }
};

if(data.data.id && 'agents' in data.data && data.data.agents.length > 0) {
    $.each(data.field_data.users, function(k, v) {
        if(data.data.agents.indexOf(v.id) >= 0) {
            user_data[v.id] = {
                first_name: v.first_name,
                last_name: v.last_name,
                id: v.id
            }
        }
        build_sort_users(k, v);
    });
}
else {
    $.each(data.field_data.users, function(k, v) {
        build_sort_users(k, v);
    });
}

$('#select_all_agents').click(function() {
    $('.select_agent').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
});

var available_user = loadViewTemplate('available_user'),
    selected_agent = loadViewTemplate('selected_agent'),
    count_agents = 0,
    count_un_agents = 0;

$('.assign_agents_popup').delegate('.queue_agent', 'click', function() {
    var data = $(this).data();
    $.tmpl(available_user, data).prependTo('#queue-view-unassigned-agent');
    console.log(_parent);
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $('.count_un_agents').html(++count_un_agents);
    $('.count_agents').html(--count_agents);
});

$('.assign_agents_popup').delegate('.user_box', 'click', function() {
    var data = $(this).data();
    $.tmpl(selected_agent, data).prependTo('#queue-view-assigned-agent');
    console.log(_parent);
    $(this).parent().remove();
    $('.count_agents').html(++count_agents);
    $('.count_un_agents').html(--count_un_agents);
});

$.each(sorted_users, function(k, v) {
    $.each(v, function(k2, v2) {
        if(!(v2.id in user_data)) {
            count_un_agents++;
            mergeTemplate(available_user, '#queue-view-unassigned-agent', v2);
        }
        else {
            count_agents++;
            mergeTemplate(selected_agent, '#queue-view-assigned-agent', v2);
        }
    });
});

$('.count_un_agents').html(count_un_agents);
$('.count_agents').html(count_agents);
}
```

Comment: Please post your `showUnAssignAgentList` function.